# Javascript ArrayBuffer- Cannot set null value to arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, web-worker, arraybuffer

```
// Creating an ArrayBuffer with a size in bytes 
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16); 

// Creating views 
var view1 = new DataView(buffer);

// Putting 1 in slot 0 
view1.setInt8(0, null);

console.log(view1.getInt8(0));
```

Result:
`0`

Expected:
`null`

How to set null/empty data? Do we have a way to check null data in arraybuffer?

Eg: We have a csv file with data like this:

`0,,1,0`

Thank you so much

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` basically represents a fixed sized chunk of memory. Various bytes in that array can be `0` but you can't possibly have a `null` value in there.

Comment: How to set empty value when we do parse csv data ,,,cool and transfer its data?

Comment: @TayDong: there's a *fixed number of byte values*. I.e. there's always 16 bytes values. i.e. 16 values, each of which is between 0 and 255. What exactly should "empty" be in this case? You could *interpret* 0 to mean "empty", when you read it, but that would mean that you can no longer represent the numeric value 0.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Sauer. It will be confusion if we mark 0 as null. What happens if the data is `0,1,,0,,cool`. It means that we can show 0, null/empty

Comment: how do you intend to write/encode the `"cool"` part into an array that takes only numbers? if your answer is charCodes, then how do you distinct between `cool,stuff` and `coolstuff`. Or in other words, how do you determine the boundaries of your columns?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN ArrayBuffer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) (emphasis mine):

> The ArrayBuffer object is used to represent a generic, fixed-length
>   raw **binary** data buffer.

I.e ArrayBuffers hold binary (Number) values only.  For this reason, the DataView API will only let you set float or integer values. `null`, however, is not a Number.  It's one of JS's [primitive values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).

You can further see this in the EcmaScript specification where in step 4 of the abstract [SetValueInBuffer](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setvalueinbuffer) operation you have, "
Assert: Type(value) is Number."  The spec does not define how to handle non-Number types, however.  One could argue that a `TypeError` should be thrown in this case, but all the implementations I checked (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Node.js) quietly cast the value to zero... which is what you're seeing.  You'll get the same behavior if you pass a `String`, `Date`, `RegEx`, `Boolean`, or `undefined`.

(If you pass a `BigInt` or `Symbol`, however, you appear to get a TypeError... weird.)

Comment: Not weird at all, implementations do call toNumber on value, so toNumber( BigIntInstance ) will throw, while toNumber( null )  will return `0`. btw it should probably be noted that truthy values will thus get cast to `1`.